# Javascript wrap multiple p tags in div after a specific class appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm wondering if it's possible to wrap all p tags in the following example in divs with the class of "wrapper" after a specific class appers in the p tags class="wrapAfterThisClass".

The markeup is dynamic, so it is very important that it is the class "wrapAfterThisClass", that is the 'trigger' for wrapping the divs around.

I've come accross solutions suggesting to wrap after nth number, but since it the content is dynamic, the length between, when the classes appears can vary.

My simplified html markup looks like this:

```
<p>1</p>
<p class="wrapAfterThisClass">2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p class="wrapAfterThisClass">5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p class="wrapAfterThisClass">7</p>
```

The output should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>1</p>
    <p class="wrapAfterThisClass">2</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p class="wrapAfterThisClass">5</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>6</p>
    <p class="wrapAfterThisClass">7</p>
</div>
```

So I've tried slice.() and wrapAll() in a jquery each loop with no luck so far.
It gives me nested wrappers wrapping them all.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it - it might be my approach that's wrong, though.

Maybe it's not even wrap or slice i need.

Cheers Bjørn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop the `.wrapAfterThisClass` elements, use `prevAll('p')` to get the previous paragraph elements, then `.addBack()` to add the current `.wrapAfterThisClass`, then just `wrapAll()`:

```
$( '.wrapAfterThisClass' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).prevAll( 'p' ).addBack().wrapAll( '<div class="wrapper" />' );
} );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szLvcwq2/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = [];

$("p").each(function(){
    a.push(this);

    if ($(this).hasClass("wrapAfterThisClass")) {
        $(a).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
        a = [];
    }
});
```